# Google Earth Api Fill polygon with color

Tags: jquery, .net, google-earth

Please take look, below code will create polygon  [check here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0XGz1Ttx6wINWpmSklkTlFRakU)   , here I want to fill it with some color what I need to do. Please assist here. I have try below code its working fine for me , I just need to fill created polygon with some color so it will look same as it in google earth.

```
   var ge;
    google.load("earth", "1");

    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
    }

    function initCB(instance) {

         ge = instance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
        ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

        var alt = 10;
        var icons = ['http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/wht-pushpin.png', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ltblu-pushpin.png', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/blue-pushpin.png'];


        var latitude = 40.30010;
        var longitude = -94.98570;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            // Create the placemark and add it to Earth.
            var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

            // Set the placemark's location.
            var point = ge.createPoint('');
            point.setLatitude(latitude);
            point.setLongitude(longitude);
            point.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);
            point.setAltitude(alt + i * 7000);
            placemark.setGeometry(point);
            placemark.setName("From Surface: " + (alt + i * 7000));

            // Define a custom icon.
            var icon = ge.createIcon('');
            icon.setHref(icons[i]);
            var style = ge.createStyle(''); //create a new style
            style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon); //apply the icon to the style
            placemark.setStyleSelector(style); //apply the style to the placemark
            // Add the placemark to Earth.
            ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
        }
        var la = ge.createLookAt('');
        la.set(latitude, longitude, alt, ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND, 0, 0, 200000);       
    //@latitude,@longitude,@centerPointlatitude,@centerPointlongitude,@polygonType
        pm = new Polygon(latitude, longitude, 39.76010, -94.92555, 5);
          ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
      }
var pi = Math.PI;

    function Polygon(lat, lon, lata, lona, sides) {
        var me = this;
        me.numsides = sides;
        me.cent = new PM(lat, lon, 'centre', 'ff00ffff');
        me.rad = new PM(lata, lona, 'outer', 'ff8080ff');
        me.setBearDist();

        var lineStringPlacemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
        me.lineString = ge.createLineString('');
        lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(me.lineString);
  //   me.lineString.setTessellate(true);
        me.lineString.setExtrude(true);
        me.lineString.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
        me.drawPolygon();

         lineStringPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
        me.lineStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
        me.lineStyle.setWidth(3);
        me.lineStyle.getColor().set('9900ffff');  // aabbggrr format
        //fill color to polygon boundry
        var polyStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getPolyStyle();
        polyStyle.getColor().set('9900ffff');
        polyStyle.setFill(1);
        polyStyle.setOutline(1);
        lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getPolyStyle().getColor().set('9900ffff'); 
       //end
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);

        google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), "mousemove", function (event) { me.movePMLoc(event); });
        google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), "mousedown", function (event) { me.completelyNewLoc(event); });
    }


    Polygon.prototype.setBearDist = function () {
        this.bear = bearing(this.cent.lat, this.cent.lon, this.rad.lat, this.rad.lon);
        this.dist = distance(this.cent.lat, this.cent.lon, this.rad.lat, this.rad.lon);
        document.getElementById('rad').innerHTML = this.dist.toPrecision(6).toString() + ' km';
        document.getElementById('bear').innerHTML = this.bear.toDeg().toPrecision(5).toString() + ' deg';
    }

    Polygon.prototype.setRad = function () {
        var latlon = destination(this.cent.lat, this.cent.lon, this.dist, this.bear);
        this.rad.setLoc(latlon[0], latlon[1]);
    }

    Polygon.prototype.colour = function (col) {
        this.lineStyle.getColor().set(col);
    }


    Polygon.prototype.drawPolygon = function () {    // Draw our Polygon
        var latlon;
        this.lineString.getCoordinates().clear();
        for (i = 0; i <= this.numsides; i++) {
            latlon = destination(this.cent.lat, this.cent.lon, this.dist, this.bear + i * 2 * pi / this.numsides);
            this.lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(latlon[0], latlon[1], 9000);
            //here we add altidue
        }
        this.areaCircum();
    }

    function PM(lat, lon, name, colour) {      // Create Placemark
        var me = this;
        me.active = false;
        me.name = name;
        me.placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(me.placemark);
        me.point = ge.createPoint('');
        me.placemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
        var IconStyle = me.placemark.getStyleSelector().getIconStyle();
        IconStyle.getColor().set(colour);
        IconStyle.getHotSpot().setXUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
        IconStyle.getHotSpot().setYUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
        IconStyle.getHotSpot().setX(0.5);
        IconStyle.getHotSpot().setY(0.5);
        me.setLoc(lat, lon);
        me.placemark.setGeometry(me.point);
        google.earth.addEventListener(me.placemark, "mousedown", function (event) { me.draw(event); });
        google.earth.addEventListener(me.placemark, "mouseup", function (event) { me.undraw(event); });
    }

    PM.prototype.setLoc = function (lat, lon) {    // set location of placemark.
        this.lat = lat.toRad();
        this.lon = lon.toRad();
        this.point.setLatLng(lat, lon.fixLon());
        document.getElementById(this.name).innerHTML = lat.toPrecision(7).toString() + ' , ' + lon.toPrecision(7).toString();
    }

    Polygon.prototype.movePMLoc = function (kmlEvent) {
        if (!this.rad.active && !this.cent.active) {
            this.colour('9900ffff');
        }
        else {
            kmlEvent.preventDefault();
            this.colour('9900ffff');
            if (this.rad.active) {
                this.rad.setLoc(kmlEvent.getLatitude(), kmlEvent.getLongitude());
                this.setBearDist();
                this.drawPolygon();
            }
            else {    // only pick up centre placemark if vertex placemark not selected
                this.cent.setLoc(kmlEvent.getLatitude(), kmlEvent.getLongitude());
                this.setRad();
                this.drawPolygon();
            }
        }
    }

    Polygon.prototype.completelyNewLoc = function (kmlEvent) {

        if (kmlEvent.getAltKey()) {
            this.cent.active = false;
            this.rad.active = true;
            this.cent.setLoc(kmlEvent.getLatitude(), kmlEvent.getLongitude());
            this.rad.setLoc(kmlEvent.getLatitude(), kmlEvent.getLongitude());
            this.colour('9900ffff');
        }
    }


    PM.prototype.draw = function () {
        this.active = true;
    }

    PM.prototype.undraw = function () {
        this.active = false;
    }


    Polygon.prototype.fetchKML = function () {

        var URL = "http://www.barnabu.co.uk/cgi-bin/polyplot.cgi"
      + "?lt=" + this.cent.lat.toDeg().toString()
      + "&ln=" + this.cent.lon.toDeg().toString()
      + "&b=" + this.bear.toDeg().toString()
      + "&d=" + this.dist.toString()
      + "&s=" + this.numsides.toString();
        window.location = URL;
    }

    Polygon.prototype.areaCircum = function () {   // compute area and circumference of Polygon

        var area = 0;
        var circum = 0;
        var latlon;
        if (this.numsides == 25) {     // area of spherical circle = 2*pi*R^2*(1-cos(radius))
            area = 2 * pi * 6371 * 6371 * (1 - Math.cos(this.dist / 6371));
            circum = 2 * pi * 6371 * (Math.sin(this.dist / 6371));
        }
        else if (this.numsides != 2) { // Spherical Polygon of n sides, theta is sum of internal angles: area = (theta-(n-2)*pi)*R^2                
            var latlon = destinationr(0, 0, this.dist, pi);
            var latlon2 = destinationr(0, 0, this.dist, pi - 2 * pi / this.numsides);
            var ang = 2 * bearing(latlon[0], latlon[1], latlon2[0], latlon2[1]);
            area = ((this.numsides * ang) - (this.numsides - 2) * pi) * 6371 * 6371;
            circum = this.numsides * distance(latlon[0], latlon[1], latlon2[0], latlon2[1]);
        }
        document.getElementById('per').innerHTML = circum.toPrecision(6).toString() + ' km';
        document.getElementById('are').innerHTML = area.toPrecision(8).toString() + ' km<sup>2</sup>';
    }

    Number.prototype.toRad = function () {  // convert degrees to radians
        return this * pi / 180;
    }

    Number.prototype.toDeg = function () {  // convert radians to degrees
        return this * 180 / pi;
    }


    Number.prototype.fixLon = function () {  // keep longitude in range -180 to 180
        lon = this;
        while (lon < -180) { lon += 360; }
        while (lon > 180) { lon -= 360; }
        return parseFloat(lon);

    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // 

    function distance(lata, lona, latb, lonb) {  // great circle distance (km)
        return Math.acos(Math.sin(lata) * Math.sin(latb) + Math.cos(lata) * Math.cos(latb) * Math.cos(lonb - lona)) * 6371;
    }

    function bearing(lata, lona, latb, lonb) {  // initial great circle bearing (rad)
        return Math.atan2(Math.sin(lonb - lona) * Math.cos(latb), Math.cos(lata) * Math.sin(latb) - Math.sin(lata) * Math.cos(latb) * Math.cos(lonb - lona))
    }

    function destination(lata, lona, dist, brng) { // destination along great circle.  returns values in degrees
        var latb = Math.asin(Math.sin(lata) * Math.cos(dist / 6371) + Math.cos(lata) * Math.sin(dist / 6371) * Math.cos(brng));
        var lonb = lona + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist / 6371) * Math.cos(lata), Math.cos(dist / 6371) - Math.sin(lata) * Math.sin(latb));
        return [180 * latb / pi, 180 * lonb / pi]

    }

    function destinationr(lata, lona, dist, brng) { // destination along great circle.  returns value in radians
        var latb = Math.asin(Math.sin(lata) * Math.cos(dist / 6371) + Math.cos(lata) * Math.sin(dist / 6371) * Math.cos(brng));
        var lonb = lona + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist / 6371) * Math.cos(lata), Math.cos(dist / 6371) - Math.sin(lata) * Math.sin(latb));
        return [latb, lonb]

    }
```

Comment: You mean the google-maps-API rather than the earth API?

Answer (score 0):

This code example could be of help: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/polygon-style.html

Comment: I have use it as     var polyColor = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getPolyStyle().getColor();
            polyColor.setA(200);
            polyColor.setB(0);
            polyColor.setG(255);
            polyColor.setR(255);    but not work for me.